# Unable to get widget to work with TPL file

Tags: javascript, php, html, whmcs

Trying to add a widget to a webpage, but after inserting the given code from the widget site the page section stops loading.  The widget code given to me is:

```
<div id="mni-membership-636958440888448977"></div>
<script src="https://thinkplexus.chambermaster.com/Content/Script/Member.js" type="text/javascript"></script>             
<script type="text/javascript">new MNI.Widgets.Member("mni-membership-636958440888448977", { member: 7846, styleTemplate: "#@id{text-align:center;position:relative}#@id .mn-widget-member-name{font-weight:700}#@id .mn-widget-member-logo{max-width:100%}" }).create();</script>
```

When adding this to any of the TPL files the contents stop being presented.  I tried adding the script portions to the PHP files and setting them to async in the header TPL file.  The site providing the code doesn't offer any type of support and I've never worked with a wiget or TPL or PHP files before to be able to discern why the generated code wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`{` and `}` are reserved in SMATRY templates.
use `{literal}`

```
 {literal}
<div id="mni-membership-636958440888448977"></div>
<script src="https://thinkplexus.chambermaster.com/Content/Script/Member.js" type="text/javascript"></script>             
<script type="text/javascript">new MNI.Widgets.Member("mni-membership-636958440888448977", { member: 7846, styleTemplate: "#@id{text-align:center;position:relative}#@id .mn-widget-member-name{font-weight:700}#@id .mn-widget-member-logo{max-width:100%}" }).create();</script>
{/literal}
```